# How to use *ngIf on own selector of a component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I have a component `<my-component>` that I want to only show if one of its properties is set. So I thought about doing something like this in `<my-component>`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myProperty">
    <div>...</div>
</ng-container>
```

The thing is the component is created in the HTML DOM. So, to avoid its creation, my assumption is that I should put the ***ngIf** on the selector of `<my-component>` in `<parent-component>`, which would make something like:

```
<parent-component>
    <my-component *ngIf="myProperty"></my-component>
</parent-component>
```

But in this case, the property **myProperty** would be set in `<my-component>` and not in `<parent-component>`.

So, if my assumption is correct, what is the way to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

You already have your solution in your question. What you are doing with

```
<parent-component>
    <my-component *ngIf="myProperty"></my-component>
</parent-component>
```

is called content projection. And the content will not be projected, when you do not allow the rendering with `*ngIf`.

### EDIT

As you forgot an important point, I have adapted my example in my StackBlitz. In order to do, what you want, you need to emit the flag from the inner component to the parent component via an `EventEmitter`. The parent component reacts to it and can therefore change the parameter to either hide or show the inner component.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dqzo73?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I forgot to mention that **myProperty** is set in ```<my-component>```. In this case **myProperty** would not be set in ```<parent-component>```.
I edit my question.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. It seems like quite a "complex" way for something like that. So I'm wondering if this is correct to put the ***ngIf** in this place or if it should just lay in the child component?

Comment: You could also just put it into the child component. It should not really matter, if the DOM displays an empty component - as long it does not contain any styling to interfere with the page

Comment: There will be no interference, so I'll go with the ***ngIf** in the child component. Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: The simples solution would be to wrap the contents of `<my-component>` (contents of my-component.component.html) in `<ng-container>` and adding `*ngIf` to it.

Solution 2: Create a service and in that service create a [behaviour subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject), inject the service in both the component, now you can toggle the value of that behaviour subject from `<my-component>` and listen in `<parent-component>` to toggle the `<my-component>`

Comment: That's what I think, too. But the component would still exist in the DOM. Is that a good practice to have a component in the DOM which does not display anything?

Comment: it depends if there is a chance that the component would be toggled often then it is good way to go since all the data would have already been initialised.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for your comment.